# Why Google Maps is not being shown in production?

Tags: android, google-maps

I am uploading an APP to Play Store. It is being uploaded well but there is one inconvenience, the maps that I am using is showing on debug mode but not when I use my application on production (when I upload the APP to the market and download it from there). A grey screen is shown when I try to open the map. I am using Google Maps.

What I have done:

- I have created a release profile to sign my APK that I use when I generate my APK. To sign the APK I do (on Android Studio) `Build > Generate Signed APK` with the Name, Alias and Password of my certificate profile.
- I have generated a Google Maps API credential using SHA-1 of the certificate that I have created in the step before and the name of the package of my project. I have restricted it to only be allowed on Android. It have generated a key to me.
- I have added these two lines on `AndroidManifest.xml` file of my project:

  ```
  <meta-data
      android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
      android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
  ```

  where `@string/google_maps_key` is the key that I have obtained in the second step and that I have stored in `strings.xml` file.

I know that there are some questions related in Stackoverflow but most of them suggest generate one of both certificates that I have already created.

Am I missing some requirement? Should I change some configuration?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: check permission in google developer api console for google places api

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you generated your Google maps key, did you put SHA-1 of your debug, or of your release certificate? If you put debug SHA-1, add release also.

**Update:**

Also, proper way to do map implementation would be to have `debug/res/values/google_maps_api.xml` with key for debug and another `release/res/values/google_maps_api.xml` with key for production. There shouldn't be key in `strings.xml`. More about this you can read [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start).

Comment: I have added the SHA-1 of the release `.jks` file

Comment: You need to add SHA-1 of your .keystore file with which you have signed the app.

Comment: Yes, the `.jks` file that I refer to is the same file that I have used to sign the APK.

Comment: There are 2 google_maps_api.xml files. One in debug folder and one in release folder. Did you put that key in both of them?

Comment: I only can see one of them that is located on `res/values/google_maps_api.xml` but it has on parhentesis `debug` mode. It is why I have located my API key on strings.xml file instead of debug google_maps_api file. I could not find any release folder.

Comment: Proper way to do maps would be to have one in debug/res/values/google_maps_api.xml with key for debug and another in release/res/values/google_maps_api.xml with key for production. (just create release folder) There shouldn't be key in strings.xml. More about it you can read [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start).

Comment: Ok, finally I got it! But release `google_maps_api` file was not being shown on Android Studio and I had to change it manually going to `app > src > release > res > values > google_maps_api` on Windows file inspector. Is it possible to access to this file from Android Studio?

Comment: Not sure. For me it's same. Only debug is shown in Android Studio.

Comment: yep, if you go to the project view you can go to src - release - res and then update your api key :)